# Spring Boot 1.5.8 not logging in JBoss EAP 7

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jboss

I am trying to run a spring boot 1.5.8 application on JBoss EAP 7, but none of the application logs are appending to the console or log file.

I have disabled spring boots default logging by excluding the logging jars as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <!-- https://programmingthoughtworkbysrinivasan.blogspot.in/2017/04/spring-152-with-jpa-21-integration-with.html -->
        <exclusions>  
            <exclusion>                             
                 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
                 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>  
            </exclusion>  
            <exclusion>                           
                 <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>  
                 <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>  
            </exclusion>  
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
       </exclusions>  
    </dependency>
```

When I start the server, I see the JBoss startup info, but I don't see any application logs, I just see this error:

```
11:26:58,032 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) Handler java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler is not defined

11:27:03,622 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) Handler java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler is not defined
```

Comment: As a starting point I'd revert Spring Boot's logging back to normal, which is using logback to log to the console, and then see if Jboss is swallowing that logging and redirecting it to it's own logging sub-system.

I guess you are forced to deploy to an app server rather than just running as a standalone JAR ? Such logging issues are typical when deploying Spring boot apps to monolithic app servers.

Comment: Because of the category `stderr` it does look like it could be Spring writing that message. I don't know how Spring Boot attempts to configure logging so that could be the issue. Do you have a logging configuration embedded in your deployment?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to re-enable your Spring Boot default logging.

After this, check if your server.log file, under JBOSS_HOME\standalone\log is now logging what you need.
If not, try creating a log category in JBoss admin console under:

Configuration: Subsystems  >>  Subsystem: Logging  >>  Log categories  >>  Add

For "category" use your package path name.
Set your desired log level and finally set "Use parent handlers" to true.
Restart the server and check again your server.log. It should work now.

If you want the same log level to be output to your JBoss console, go back to JBoss admin console under:

Configuration: Subsystems  >>  Subsystem: Logging  >>  Log handlers  >>  Console

And edit the console log level to the same level you need.

Comment: yep in my case i was resolving some jboss eap 7.1 classpath conflicts and while doing it i excluded too much including the logback classic. i put it back, everything magically worked

Answer (score 0):

You should keep your parent package and log level in JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml as mentioned below

```
<logger category="com.iedr">
    <level name="INFO"/>
</logger>
```

Here my parent package is com.iedr and log level i wanted is INFO.
You should add this one to your logging subsystem, as mentioned below

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:8.0">
<console-handler name="CONSOLE">
    <level name="INFO"/>
    <formatter>
        <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
</console-handler>
<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
    <formatter>
        <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
    <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <append value="true"/>
</periodic-rotating-file-handler>
<logger category="com.arjuna">
    <level name="WARN"/>
</logger>
<logger category="io.jaegertracing.Configuration">
    <level name="WARN"/>
</logger>
<logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
    <level name="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
<logger category="sun.rmi">
    <level name="WARN"/>
</logger>
<logger category="com.iedr">
    <level name="INFO"/>
</logger>
<root-logger>
    <level name="INFO"/>
    <handlers>
        <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
        <handler name="FILE"/>
    </handlers>
</root-logger>
<formatter name="PATTERN">
    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
</formatter>
<formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
    <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
</formatter>
```